# How hide console C# app in tray second time?

Tags: c#, console, tray

I have this console app on C# code example. This code working fine. But I have a problem when I already get app from the tray. If I press MINIMIZE button the app does not put it in the tray again.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE); 

var notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();


 using (
        var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.pngegg.ico"))
{
  notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(stream);
}

notifyIcon.Text = "Some text";
notifyIcon.Visible = true;

notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Same text", "Same text", ToolTipIcon.Info);

notifyIcon.MouseClick += NotifyIcon_MouseClick;

Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;

                              
Application.Run();           


}

private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Some text...");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

private static void NotifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   try
       {
         var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
         ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW); 
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
               
       }
     }
```

But, I can`t hide the console in the tray the second time (after showing the window from the tray) by pressing MINIMIZE button on the window console.
This is possible in console app C#? How I can hide the console app in the tray again?